# What does it mean that my app doesn't support gracefully shutting down?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have published an app to the Windows Phone Store and was given the following warning:

> App Policies: 10.4.2 Graceful Shutdown
>   The app supports graceful shutdown. The app must handle exceptions raised by the any of the managed or native system API and not close unexpectedly. An app that closes unexpectedly fails certification. The app must continue to run and remain responsive to user input after the exception is handled.
>   Expected Result
>   1. Launch your app. 2. Navigate throughout the app, and then close the app. 3. Verify that unexpected behavior does not occur during the closing process. 4. Verify that the app remains responsive to user input and user interaction following an app error.

I'm not exactly sure what the issue is here, and how to solve it.  I'm thinking that it may have to do with the memory footprint of my app, but that doesn't make sense as it is only 1 mb.

[Editor's note: OP isn't a native speaker of English, which may be part of the problem]

Code :

```
List<WebBrowser> wbs = new List<WebBrowser>();
        List<PivotItem> pis = new List<PivotItem>();
        List<Uri> uris = new List<Uri>();
        public void mtdUlusal()
        {
            grd.Children.Clear();
            uris.Clear();
            pis.Clear();
            wbs.Clear();
            List<string> headers = new List<string>();
            headers.Add("Hürriyet");
            headers.Add("Milliyet");
            headers.Add("Posta");
            headers.Add("Radikal");
            headers.Add("Zaman");
            headers.Add("Sözcü");
            headers.Add("Cumhuriyet");
            headers.Add("Sol Haber");
            headers.Add("Sabah");
            headers.Add("Star");
            headers.Add("Akşam");
            headers.Add("Türkiye");
            headers.Add("Anadolu Ajansı");
            headers.Add("BirGün");

            Uri uri0 = new Uri("http://cep.hurriyet.com.tr/");
            uris.Add(uri0);

            Pivot pvt = new Pivot();
            pvt.Title = "ULUSAL GAZETELER";
            grd.Children.Add(pvt);
            pvt.Background = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 113, 206));
            //pvt.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(125, 100, 0, 75));


            Uri bln = new Uri("about:blank");

            for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
            {
                PivotItem pItem = new PivotItem();
                pItem.Header = headers[i];
                pis.Add(pItem);
                Grid grdUlusal = new Grid();
                WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
                wb.IsScriptEnabled = true;
                wbs.Add(wb);
                grdUlusal.Children.Add(wb);
                pItem.Content = grdUlusal;
                pvt.Items.Add(pItem);
            }
            wbs[0].Navigate(uris[0]);
            pvt.SelectionChanged += Pvt_SelectionChanged;
        }

        private void Pvt_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Pivot pvt = (Pivot)sender;
            Uri uri1 = new Uri("http://wap.milliyet.com.tr/");
            Uri uri2 = new Uri("http://m.posta.com.tr/");
            Uri uri3 = new Uri("http://www.radikal.com.tr/");
            Uri uri4 = new Uri("http://www.zaman.com.tr/mobile.action");
            Uri uri5 = new Uri("http://m.sozcu.com.tr/");
            Uri uri6 = new Uri("http://www.cumhuriyet.com.tr/");
            Uri uri7 = new Uri("http://haber.sol.org.tr/");
            Uri uri8 = new Uri("http://www.sabah.com.tr/");
            Uri uri9 = new Uri("http://mobil.stargazete.com/default.asp");
            Uri uri10 = new Uri("http://m.aksam.com.tr/");
            Uri uri11 = new Uri("http://m.turkiyegazetesi.com.tr/");
            Uri uri12 = new Uri("http://www.aa.com.tr/");
            Uri uri13 = new Uri("http://www.birgun.net/");

            uris.Add(uri1);
            uris.Add(uri2);
            uris.Add(uri3);
            uris.Add(uri4);
            uris.Add(uri5);
            uris.Add(uri6);
            uris.Add(uri7);
            uris.Add(uri8);
            uris.Add(uri9);
            uris.Add(uri10);
            uris.Add(uri11);
            uris.Add(uri12);
            uris.Add(uri13);
            for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
            {
                if (pvt.SelectedItem == pis[i])
                {
                    wbs[i].Navigate(uris[i]);

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Does the app run fine when deployed from Visual Studio, but crash immediately when deployed from the Store? If so, one common issue is trying to write to files in your install folder. Do you do that?

Comment: No, when i deploy from Visual Studio it crash again and giving an error message. It's : out of memory at line : 1.

Comment: Do you have infinite recursion during startup? Can you post your code and / or use the debugger to determine where you run out of memory?

Comment: Code is too long :( . I have 13 WebBrowsers and when I run the program 13 WebBrowsers should Navigate different addresses, and giving out of memory at line : 1 error

Comment: I'm not surprised if you run out of memory using thirteen WebBrowser controls at the same time. What are you trying to do that requires so many browsers at once? Can you use an HttpClient object instead to download the data?

Comment: Hello Master :) How to use the HttpClient?, HttpClient shows html code -to the best of my knowledge- @PeterTorr-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display HTML then you should just have a single `WebBrowser` control and navigate to a new URL whenever the user selects that pivot. For example, here is some simple XAML to put on a page:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <phone:Pivot SelectionChanged="OnPivotChanged">
    <phone:PivotItem Header="microsoft"/>
    <phone:PivotItem Header="msdn"/>
    <phone:PivotItem Header="onedrive"/>
    <phone:PivotItem Header="office"/>
  </phone:Pivot>

  <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="browser" Grid.Row="1" 
                    IsScriptEnabled="True" 
                    Navigated="OnBrowserNavigated" 
                    NavigationFailed="OnNavigationFailed"/>
  <TextBlock x:Name="errorMessage" FontSize="38" 
              Text="sorry, couldn't navigate to that site :-(" 
              TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="30,0" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
              Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</Grid>
```

And here is the associated code:

```
private void OnPivotChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  browser.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
  errorMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
  var newItem = e.AddedItems[0] as PivotItem;
  var site = new Uri("http://www." + newItem.Header.ToString() + ".com/");
  browser.Navigate(site);
}

private void OnBrowserNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  browser.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
{
  errorMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

It's pretty basic without much error checking, but you should get the idea. Running this on the emulator seemed stable around 75MB per the profiler, which is well within the limits of a Store app.